# How to use plugin to reduce size when import lodash

Tags: reactjs, plugins

Here is my code : `import _ from 'lodash'`;

I want to use `babel-plugin-transform-imports` to reduce size of folder when "yarn build".

But I don't know how to set up plugin and config in `wepack.config.js`

Thank you so much

Comment: did you check https://www.npmjs.com/package/babel-plugin-transform-imports ?

Comment: I did it, but it didn't work

Answer (score 1):

There is three way to reduce:
1. When in development, you can include the folder where you are going to compile by config the loaders, so the file outside this folder won't be compiled. Loader config are like the following code:

```
{
    test: /\.(js|mjs|jsx)$/,
    include: path.resolve(__dirname,"src"),//important
    use: {
        loader: 'babel-loader'
    }
}
```

2、 You can use DDL to pre-compile the third-party library.

e.g.

Firstly create vendor.js, that is to say you need to bundle it by another webpack config.

```
const webpack = require('webpack')
const library = '[name]_lib'
const path = require('path')
module.exports = {
  mode:"production",
  entry: {
    vendors: ['lodash']
  },
  output: {
    filename: '[name].dll.js',
    path: path.join(__dirname,"dist/vendor"),
    library
  },
  plugins: [
    new webpack.DllPlugin({
      path: path.join(__dirname, 'dist/[name]-manifest.json'),
      // This must match the output.library option above
      name: library
    }),
  ]
}
```

And then you need to include mainfest.json in your project webpack config:

```
plugins: [
    new webpack.DllReferencePlugin({
      context: __dirname,
      manifest: path.join(__dirname, 'dist/vendors-manifest.json'),
    })
]
```

3、 You can use externals to exclude it, you can config it like:

```
externals : {
    lodash : {
      commonjs: 'lodash',
      amd: 'lodash',
      root: '_' // indicates global variable
    }
}
```

And don't forget to include lodsh script in HTML, because webpack don't compile or include it in your bundle. If you don't include ,the broswer will throw an error.

You can check more usage at Webpack website:

https://webpack.js.org/configuration/externals/
https://webpack.js.org/plugins/dll-plugin/